# urlrewriter issue: Query string is duplicated shown?

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I'm using urlRewritingNet. My web.config is here>>

```
<add name="HOME" virtualUrl="^~/(.*)/Default.aspx" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/Default.aspx?PageTitle=$1" ignoreCase="true"/>
```

My query string is here:

```
www.domain.com/home/default.aspx
```

This works. But I'm insert LoginStatus control. When click on the login control to logout, Page url was like this `www.domain.com/home/default.aspx?PageTitle=home`

`Request.Querystring["PageTitle"]` result is `home,home`

How to stop this duplicated query string?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, I did something like following;

change your destinationUrl to "`~/Default.aspx/$1`"

and catch it with `Request.PathInfo.Substring(1);`