# how to fix request.querystring before pageload

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

My previous question is [urlrewriter problem: Query string is duplicated shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516151/urlrewriter-problem-query-string-is-duplicated-shown)

I'm developing asp.net web site. But has a one problem. There is duplicated query string like this `www.domainname.com/default.aspx?Query=Value1&Query=Value2` 
I'm using to too many pages like this `Request.QueryString["Query"]`. But this return `Value1,Value2` . I don't want to fix this problem to too many pages. I want to fix querystring before pageload. I think that Maybe will write some function on global.asax. But i don't know to how write it.

You have a any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive Request.QueryString itself is read-only.  You could setup your own collection containing whatever you want to use:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> qsValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys) {
    if (Request.QueryString[key].Count > 1) {
        qsValues[key] = Request.QueryString[key][0];
    }
    else {
        qsValues[key] = Request.QueryString[key];
    }
}
```

Or just access the first entry in the list of values for that query string parameter in your code:

```
if (Request.QueryString["Query"].Count > 1) {
    queryValue = Request.QueryString[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static bool bi = false;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (bi == false)
            {
                bi = true;
                Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx?id=null");
            }
            else if (bi)
            {
                string s = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();

                if (s != "null")
                {
                    switch (s)
                    {
                        case "News":
                            {
                                ProjectsManagment.Controls.AllNews n = new Controls.AllNews();
                                MainContentsAsp.Controls.Add(n);
                                break;
                            }
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```